# Hide featured products on WooCommerce shop and archives pages for guest users or for a certain user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I am attempting to restrict products from appearing in archives/search results if a visitor is NOT LOGGED IN **OR** if there user Role is "Customer"

I'm using this snippet:

```php
// Check User Role

function banks_has_user_role($check_role){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(in_array( $check_role, (array) $user->roles )){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// // Hide products in specific category from not logged-in users and user role customer
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'exclude_products_fom_unlogged_users', 10, 2 );
function exclude_products_fom_unlogged_users( $tax_query, $query ) {
    global $user, $product;
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN', // or 'NOT IN' to exclude feature products
);
    }
    
    else if(banks_has_user_role('customer')){
        $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN', // or 'NOT IN' to exclude feature products
);
    }
    return $tax_query;
}


// The query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $products,
    'orderby'             => $orderby,
    'order'               => $order == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query // <===
) );
```

When testing I was certain I got the **not logged in** state to work as featured products no longer displayed but I seem to get infinite loading now. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using unnecessary steps. This shortened and modified version of your code attempt should suffice to hide featured products for customers who are not logged in or for users with the user role `'customer'`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // NOT for backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return $tax_query;

    // Guest user OR user role = customer
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        );
    }

    return $tax_query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Works a charm! Always nice to see answers like this as I was way off with my own code.